Problem w/Roles and Permissions on Renamed Site in Sitecore following Deployments
I'm facing a recurring issue with our Sitecore installation which integrates with Active Directory for managing user access and permissions. Recently, we changed the name of one of our websites within the Sitecore content tree. Since this change, every time we deploy new updates, the roles previously assigned to the renamed site seem to be unrecognized, and the permissions are lost.
Each time, I find myself needing to manually go into the Security Editor, select the necessary role, and reassign the permissions to the content item that corresponds to the renamed site. As you can  imagine, this isn't really going to work long term
Has anyone experienced similar issues when renaming content tree items in Sitecore, particularly when those items have roles and permissions managed through Active Directory integration? If so, how did you resolve or work around this issue to maintain role and permission continuity through deployments?
I appreciate thoughts or suggestions
Thanks
I've tried looking at the RoleInRoles table in SQL thinking that might provide a hint but that, thus far, doesn't appear to be the cause but still checking if the issue may somehow be DB related.
